# How do I check if a string has an ASCII letter in it?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how can I find out whether a string has a-z in it? Is there a simple function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
/[a-z]/.test(myString)
```

I guess.

Comment: Yikes; thanks, outis. That's what I get for answering before coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
function checkkey(v) {
     if (/\W/.test(v.value)) {
        alert("Please enter alphanumerics only");
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

W is a shortcut to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Change W to: [^a-zA-Z_]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Not sure what you mean by `a-z` - that exact string, or simply lower case letters? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: If a string has an alphabet in it , return true. Otherwise, return false. For example, 392342 would return false.

Comment: Helpful hint: Apparently in some indic languages »alphabet« is the term for »character«.